# How to set an multiple alarm in python

Tags: python, django, multithreading, celery

I want to set multiple alarm in python. What is the recommended way of setting it up? My use-case is that I've threshold time for `N` variables. When the current time reaches the threshold value, I want all the variables with that threshold values.

Here's my apprach:-

```
threshold_time_list = [get list all times from the DB]    

current_time = datetime.now()

[i for i in threshold_time_list if i==current_time]
```

But this is very inefficient way of doing it since I might have 250+ variables like `a/b/c`.
And also I have to check this condition every second(cronjob). Is there a better way of doing it?

I found on SO, this can be done using threading and making the thread to go to sleep for `threshod - current_time`. But running 250 threads parallely is again an issue, since I've been facing an issue in my production where Django gets hanged (dont know why) and I need to  restart the server to make it work again. We're asssuming that Django might get out of threads for processing, hence making 250 more threads is cumbersome.

Also if someone knows , why does Django gets hang in b/w the running live product it will be beneficial.

Can this alarm question be done in celery?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [sched](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) module.  This lets you create any number of scheduled tasks, then run them when they kick off, one at a time.